# BizTalk orchestration XML tag definition for "signal"

Tags: xml, biztalk, workflow-foundation, biztalk-2009, biztalk-orchestrations

I have an orchestration that contains the elements:

```
<om:Element Type="MessageAssignment" OID="..." LowerBound="1.1" HigherBound="10.4">
    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False"/>
```

I cannot find any documentation on the attributes LowerBound or HigherBound, or the property Signal mean.

Please could someone explain the significance and the effect of changing these, They have changed between two revisions in source control for a legacy system inherited by my current team, and I would like to understand what affect if any these will have.

Comment: Don't pay too much attention to that changes. I'm not shure about what  do they mean, but i think its element's positioning coordinates. They are not affecting anything.

Comment: I have been trying to investigate the purpose of Signal property someday. I decided that boolean value of this property changes almost randomly.

Comment: Xml part of orchestration exists only for designer view, pay more attention to Xlang part where actual orchestration logic is stored.

Comment: Did anyone find out what that property "signal" is?
I tried and it seems like it is random and doesn't really change anything.

Answer (score 1):

.odx is not publicly documented because they are Designer generated/consumed.

My advise would be don't worry about it.  Run your normal test process and it everything works, you should be good.

Were there any other changes in the source?

Comment: I understand that the bounds attributes are just about the layout of the designer, but I do not understand what the signal property represents.  The deployment and config management bods are interested, functionality remains unchanged, bu they are concerned that the code (all be it generated code) has changed without any requested/authorized change and want an explanation

Comment: I have just been informed that there was a change to the expression in the messageassignment shape, so now its is a case of finding out what the signal property represents and its potential impact